# Remote "origin" does not support the LFS locking API //trying to upload model.h5 file in github which is more than 100mb using lfs

Tags: git, github, deployment

Remote "origin" does not support the LFS locking API. Consider disabling it with:
$ git config lfs.https://github.com/rajghadi1/trial.git/info/lfs.locksverify false
Post "https://github.com/rajghadi1/trial.git/info/lfs/locks/verify": dial tcp 13.234.176.102:443: i/o timeout
error: failed to push some refs to 'https://github.com/rajghadi1/trial.git'[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fNQZa.png)

Answer (score 1):

The problem you're seeing here is this one:

```
Post "https://github.com/rajghadi1/trial.git/info/lfs/locks/verify": dial tcp 13.234.176.102:443: i/o timeout
```

That means that the operation timed out.  It's likely that you have some sort of network problem which is preventing you from connecting to GitHub.  The request in this case is relatively small, and therefore it should not be the cause of timeouts itself.

If you have a proxy or TLS MITM device, or an antivirus or firewall other than Windows Defender or Windows Firewall, try switching to a different network or completely removing the software and rebooting.  Usually these things are the cause of network problems, but it may also be a problem with your ISP.

Answer (score 1):

Can you check if you are using an older version of git? This might happen if you are not using latest version of TLS library.

alternatively, though not recommended, you can disable it by running the command as suggested in the error message itself,

```
git config lfs.https://github.com/rajghadi1/trial.git/info/lfs.locksverify false
```